# HTML, error al ir de pagina en pagina

Tags: php, html

Tengo un error al realizar mi pagina web, tengo una base de datos para acceder la cual realice con php y las paginas siguientes las tengo en php.

Mi error viene cuando quiero ir a la una página me salta OBJETO NO LOCALIZADO.

```
<a href="pantallas/index.html"><input type="button" value="Añadir producto"></a>
```

cuando pulso el la referencia de añadir producto, si que me va donde tiene que ir, el problema es al llegar a la pagina de añadir producto.

Me ocurre que me salta objeto no localizado.

hago la referencia así tanto para volver a la página anterior como para salir al login.

```
<a href="pantallas\pag2.html"><input type="button" value="volver"></a>

<a href="cerrar.php"><input type="button" value="Cerrar sesion "></a>
```

¿alguien tiene alguna idea de que puede pasar?

Muchas gracias de ante mano por la ayuda.

Comment: no será por que la ruta dice "pantallas\pag2.html" cuando deberia decir "pantallas/pag2.html"

Comment: ya consegui sacar el problema.

Muchas gracias a todos por la ayuda =)

Answer (score 0):

Cuando utilizas urls con subcarpetas, al navegar en las siguientes direcciones toma en cuenta la ubicación de dicha carpeta.

Debes añadir un `/` antes de cada enlace para solucionar este error.

Tus enlaces deberían quedar así:

```
<a href="/pantallas/index.html"><input type="button" value="Añadir producto"></a>

<a href="/pantallas/pag2.html"><input type="button" value="volver"></a>

<a href="/cerrar.php"><input type="button" value="Cerrar sesion"></a>
```

Comment: Si que me soluciono a el de cerrar, pero en los otros me va pero me redirige paginas que son las mismas pero como que no pillara el css bien y luego no me funcionan bien los botones de la pagina

Comment: Prueba agregar lo mismo a las direcciones de los archivos css. Un `/` antes de cada dirección. Y si tienes archivos .js lo mismo.